# Google sheets script HTML output an entire row on screen

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, scripting

I am trying to write a script to output on screen an entire row from a google sheet... Can someone help me with my function? I would like it to be called via URL, such as when it is opened in a browser, it just prints the entire row on the screen.

```
function doGet(e){
var range = e.parameter.range;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById($SHEET_ID);
var data = sheet.getActiveSheet().getDataRange(range).getValues();

return ContentService.createTextOutput(data);

}
```

Comment: What does it print now?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.

Comment: [Edit] your question to provide [mre]. FYI, there's no `getRange()` method anywhere in  the script that you provided

Comment: function doGet(e){
  var param = e.parameter.param;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1$SHEET_ID");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = sheet.getRange(param);
  var value = data.getValues();
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(value);

}

Comment: That seems to have worked!

Comment: If your want to add a answer, add it in the answer box below clearly explaining the issue and the solution  and code.

Answer (score 1):

It works quite well like this; it does output the values on screen as described:

```
function doGet(e){
    var param = e.parameter.param;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("$SHEET_ID");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //or whichever sheet# 
    var data = sheet.getRange(param);
    var value = data.getValues();

return ContentService.createTextOutput(value);

}
```